# How do I use a boost?

Tags: temple-run-2

I have a daily quest to use 10 boosts, but I can't figure out what that means. How do I use a boost?

Comment: Um, do you not know that "boost" is in the game? Or do you have some other trouble finnishing the quest?

Comment: No, i don’t understand that “boost” , because boost from powerup i don’t think it is ... And yes i have a trouble finnishing the quest because i don’t know what it is “use boost”

Answer (score 1):

When you choose the runner you want click on menu
Up in the top left corner there is an emblem probably a gem. 
Click on it then choose boost. When you play any of the places on your map watch the top left corner of the screen. When it turns all green double tap anywhere on your screen and your runner will speed off by itself. That’s a boost.